# onlineMeetingUrl is coming null and onlineMeetingProvider is 'unknown' while creating event for a user by using graph api, Why?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using graph api to create events for almost 50 users and for all users when i am creating event with
`isOnlineMeeting: true`  and  `onlineMeetingProvider: 'teamsForBusiness'` keys in request body events are creating successfully and returning the response

**endpoint I am calling is**

```
axios.post(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userId}/calendar/events`,requestBody,options)
```

**request body**

```
 requestBody = {
    subject:MeetSubject,
    start:{
        dateTime:isoStart,
        timezone:'UTC'
    },
    end:{
        dateTime:isoEnd,
        timezone:'UTC'
    },

    recurrence: recurrenceData,
    attendees: [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: attendeEmail,
          name: attendeName,
        },
        type: 'required',
      },
    ],
    isOnlineMeeting: true,
    onlineMeetingProvider: 'teamsForBusiness'
  };
```

**response**

```
{
....
....
onlineMeetingProvider: 'teamsForBusiness',
onlineMeeting: {
      joinUrl: 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l...../.
    }
  }
}
```

But for a perticular user when I am creating the event with simillar request body so event is created successfully but in the response event Object i am getting

**response**

```
{
....
....
onlineMeetingProvider: 'unknown',
onlineMeeting: null
}
```

why it is like that
is there something which i am missing for that perticular i don't know what

and app has those permissions already

```
TeamSettings.Read.All
TeamSettings.ReasWrite.All
OnlineMeetings.Read
OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite
```

Comment: Please add info about endpoints you are calling. You say that for particular user you send request with similar (not same) request body which means that the request body is different. Could you share request body?

Comment: Could you call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userId}/calendar for user where you can't create online meeting and check whether the returned calendar has set allowedOnlineMeetingProviders property? If user's calendar has empty allowedOnlineMeetingProviders then it can cause the issue you are facing when creating an event with online meeting

Comment: @user2250152 its returning
 allowedOnlineMeetingProviders: [ 'teamsForBusiness' ],
 defaultOnlineMeetingProvider: 'teamsForBusiness',